# Where is the delete account button in Thunderbird on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, delete, button

I was unable to find the "Delete account" button in Thunderbird on Ubuntu 12.04. Saw posts saying that I can find it at the bottom left side, but could not find it. Please help me find that button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to `Edit` → `Account Settings`, select the account, go to the bottom left `Account Actions` and choose `Remove Account`:

[image: remove acccount]

If your screen is too small you have to maximize the window first.

Comment: As of 2021-05-06, Thunderbird may not show the *Remove Account* option, thus preventing the user from deleting the account. In such case, it's necessary to manually delete it, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1335204/389062).