# Where is the delete button account button in Thunderbird 17.0.8?

Tags: thunderbird

How I can remove an account in my Thunderbird? I have Thunderbird 17.0.8.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
Go to Edit -> Account Settings -> 'Down left side' there is an "Account Actions" Button

Select 'Account Actions' -> 'Remove Account'
```

Note:->  If you are using Laptop then "Account Settings" window is showing as small so, down side button will not visible then maximize the window to see all options

Select 'Account Actions' button in that have "Remove Account" button to delete your Thunderbird account.

For see in graphic view [Click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131395/where-is-the-delete-account-button-in-thunderbird-on-ubuntu-12-04).